# How to perform search in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i'm having issues searching the articles on a blog post i'm currently working on it keeps giving me errors

this is my views.py

```
def search(request):
    template = 'articles/search.html'

    query = request.GET.get('q')

    results = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(movie_name__icontains=query))

    context = {'results': results}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

and this my url.py

```
url(r'^results/$', views.search, name="search"),
```

and this is the error it keeps giving me 
http://dpaste.com/2DZQDZ3

Comment: The error url doesn't open.

Comment: The error seems to happen in another place: in `views.py` 63 line where you do: `articles = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)`

Comment: looks like you pasted the wrong code for the search url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from 
File "C:\Users\dafom\Desktop\moviebackend\articles\views.py" in articleDetails
  63.     articles = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)

Trying to fetch data using get() throws an exception when the object is not found. You either handle it with try/ catch or django's in-built get_object_or_404() which throws a standard 404 error when the object is not found.

```python
 from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
 get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
```

other than that the search looks good. You might want to add distinct() to result otherwise you would get duplicate results.

```python
results = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | movie_name__icontains=query)).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a try/except block when you're using the `get()` query method as in  
`File "C:\Users\dafom\Desktop\moviebackend\articles\views.py" in articleDetails 63. articles = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)` from your error message.

Here's an example from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    e = Entry.objects.get(id=3)
    b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("Either the entry or blog doesn't exist.")
```